# Preventing ggplot2 from cutting off charts in a Sweave PDF

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, knitr, sweave

When generating a list of charts using ggplot2, how would you make sure that each chart is printed on its own page in a pdf?

I'm creating a script in an R Sweave (.Rnw) file. In the script, I'm creating a list of over thirty charts using ggplot2 and knitr. The second chart code creates 30+ charts using a loop. How could I write it so that each new chart prints on a new page?

Here's some examples of two different codes I use to create the charts:

```
<<Benchmarks1,echo=FALSE, results=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

versions<-unique(Testdf[order(Testdf$Number), ][,2])

Testdf <- Testdf[complete.cases(Testdf),]
setDT(Testdf)
Testdf <- Testdf[, Benchmark := Value[Category== "Time"][which.min(Number[Category == "Time"])], by = FileName]

Testdf$Version<-factor(Testdf$Version, levels = versions)
Testdf$Deviation<-Testdf$Value- Testdf$Benchmark
Testdf$DeviationP<-(Testdf$Value- Testdf$Benchmark)/Testdf$Benchmark

g <-ggplot(subset(Testdf, Category == 'Time') , aes(color = Value, x = Version, y = DeviationP, group = FileName)) + 
  geom_line(size=.25) + geom_point(aes(shape = Build), size = 1.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,15)) +
  ylab("Run Time Deviation from Benchmark (%)") +  
  scale_colour_gradient(name = 'Run Time (min)',low = 'blue', high = 'red') + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-3,7)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90, vjust = .5)) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.1)) + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"mm"))
g
@
```

---

```
<<Charts, echo=FALSE, results=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)

versions<-unique(Testdf[order(Testdf$Number), ][,2])
Testdf$Version<-factor(Testdf$Version, levels = versions)

files<-unique(Testdf$FileName)

for (i in 1:36){
p <- ggplot(subset(Testdf, FileName== files[i]), aes(x=Version, y=Value, group=FileName)) 
p <- p + geom_line(size=.25) + geom_point(shape = 19, size = 1.2, colour = 'red') + 
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,15)) + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom="line") + 
  ggtitle(files[i]) +
  facet_grid(Category ~ ., scales  = "free", space = "fixed") +
  ylab("Value") + xlab("Version") +
  expand_limits(y=0) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10, angle = 90, vjust = .5)) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.1)) + theme(panel.margin = unit(0.3, "lines")) + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"mm"))
print(p)
}
@
```

I don't think there's any reason to provide an example of what the data looks like. If you think otherwise, let me know in the comments.

Here's what I get in the PDF Report:

[image: ChartCutOff1]

[image: ChartCutOff2]

**The bold gray line is the page break**

Is there anyway I can force ggplot2 to print charts on the next page?
I'd prefer if there was a way to do this *only* when the 2nd chart won't fit on the same page. If for some reason the two charts would both fit on the page, then I'd be fine having both there.

Comment: This is a knitr or sweave problem, not a ggplot problem. ggplot doesn't place charts in the PDF. So which are you using, knitr or sweave (both can use .Rnw files, but the available options are different)? And can you show your entire code chunk that prints these plots?

Comment: @Gregor I'm still a relative newbie so I'm not 100% sure how to answer. In R studio, I started a new R Sweave file (.Rnw) but I'm using the package knitr in my file. I edited the code chunks.

Comment: Please post a complete (but minimal) .Rnw file that produces the problem. It's really hard to troubleshoot these kinds of questions when you show a lot of code that's essentially unrelated to the core issue at-hand.

Comment: A good start might be to use the figure float environment for the graphics.  That should keep all the graphics visible.  The primary issue here is LaTeX, not knitr or sweave.